# How to set session in php?

Tags: php, session

I am having a project where after user logs in user will see some `society list`.
onclick particular society he will enter into dashboard of it.
So, if user clicks on society-1 after that he should be display only `society-1's` data.

```
<h6>Please select your society</h6>
   <?php
       $sql = mysqli_query($conn,'select * from `society`');
       $_SESSION['society'] = $sql['societyId'];
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 

       {?>
      <h4 style="color: #000;"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
      style="color: black;" href="home.php"><?php echo $row['societyName']?></a>
     </h4>
  <?php }?>
```

this is my code to display all societies from database. now if i choose any of them it should display only particular society's data.

i have `societyId` in my all respective tables as a foreign key.

Comment: start the session using session_start(); at page very top and assin like this $_SESSION['nam']='value';

Comment: [Reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set Session you must first have the session started.
You should have it started on every file, so put this line of code at the start of the PHP Document.

```
session_start();
```

To set data it's simply as what you are already doing.

```
$_SESSION["username"] = "Stack";
```